# how to append backslash to javascript variabl

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a control which has the following.

```
"time1":{    
       "regex": ^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$,
       "alertText": "* Invalid Time"
    }
```

i have a method which will take the following inputs :

```
//for regex validation
    function inputFilter(inputbox, regex) {

        var regExStart = "/\\";
        var regExEnd = "/\\";

        consol.log("Reg Ex Validation : "+regExStart + regex + regExEnd);
        txb.value = inputbox.value.replace( regex, "");
    }
```

when i call the above method i get the following : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I am not sure that whether i make mistake in constructing the `regex`. i think it should be like :

```
 /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/ and i have to append `//` with my `regex`.
```

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Try replacing `consol` by `console`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile regular expressions from strings like so:

```
var regexCompiled = new RegExp(regex);
txb.value = inputbox.value.replace(regexCompiled, "");
```

Also, you are probably missing quotation marks around your pattern:

```
"regex": "^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$",
```

and of course, you could instead use a regex there already, like so:

```
"regex": /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-3]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/,
```

then you would not even have to compile it.

Comment: i still get this : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Thanks, this is how i create my input box : `dataInputBox = '<input type=text name="'+id+'" id="'+id+'" maxlength='+maxlength+' title="'+tooltip+'" onKeyUp=inputFilter(this,"'+regex+'");/>';` is there any issue here???

Comment: Nah, but where do you do that, and where does that data come from?

Comment: everything is working fine if don't add `onKeyUp..`method. when i checked DOM, this is how the created element is `<input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" maxlength="70" title="Ex: John" onkeyup="inputFilter(this,&quot;^(?![" ])(?=".*[\w]).{1,70}(?&lt;!\s)$&quot;);/">`

Comment: Try this: `onKeyUp="inputFilter(this,\''+regex+'\');"/>';`. You are missing quotation marks around the attribute.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37593/discussion-between-anto-and-opatut)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular expresion in javascript like this

```
var re = /^[a-z]$/g;
```

or

```
var re = new RegExp("^[a-z]$", "g");
```

see [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)